# SqlDependency from ASP.NET to Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, signalr

I have in the hub SignalR a method with SQLDependecy .
Can I get this return in the Xamarin ? 
For example in the client side ASP.NET I get by JavaScript below .
I need this dependecy in android , if somebody worked with SignalR hellp me please to find solution. Is not usualy hub connection , I not found to read for SQLDependecy in the hub for android .

```
    public static void Show()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displayStatus();
    }

public static IEnumerable<Products> GetData()
{

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBase"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Guests] FROM  [1]", connection))
        {
            // Make sure the command object does not already have
            // a notification object associated with it.
            command.Notification = null;
            SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBase"].ConnectionString);
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                    .Select(x => new Products()
                    {
                        Guests = x.GetString(0),
                    }).ToList();


        }
    }
}
private static void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    Show();
}
```

```
  $(function () {

      // Proxy created on the fly
      var job = $.connection.myHub;

      // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
      job.client.displayStatus = function () {
          getData();
      };

      // Start the connection
      $.connection.hub.start();
      getData();
  });

  function getData() {
      var $tbl = $('#tbl');
      $.ajax({
          url: 'index.aspx/GetData',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          success: function (data) {
              debugger;
              if (data.d.length > 0) {
                  var newdata = data.d;
                  $tbl.empty();
                  $tbl.append(' <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Last Executed Date</th><th>Status</th></tr>');
                  var rows = [];
                  for (var i = 0; i < newdata.length; i++) {
                      rows.push(' <tr><td>' + newdata[i].Guests + '</td></tr>');
                  }
                  $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
              }
          }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the Xamarin Client for SignalR.

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client

As you can see below, you are able to do almost the same.

```
public class SignalRClient : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private HubConnection Connection;
    private IHubProxy ChatHubProxy;

    public delegate void MessageReceived(string username, string message);
    public event MessageReceived OnMessageReceived;

    public SignalRClient(string url)
    {
        Connection = new HubConnection(url);

        Connection.StateChanged += (StateChange obj) => {
            OnPropertyChanged("ConnectionState");
        };

        ChatHubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("Chat");
        ChatHubProxy.On<string, string>("MessageReceived", (username, text) => {
            OnMessageReceived?.Invoke(username, text);
        });
    }

    public void SendMessage(string username, string text)
    {
        ChatHubProxy.Invoke ("SendMessage", username, text);
    }
  ....
```

You can see the complete example here https://github.com/schneidenbach/Xamarin-Forms-and-SignalR-Example.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms

Comment: Jesus Angulo yes I know thank you very much ! I need to understand it posibil what I want to know ? Usual chatHubProxy not work .